# How to merge 2 userscripts or replace a script that on Tampermonkey with new version

Tags: namespaces, tampermonkey, userscripts

I'd like to describe my problem related to Tampermonkey script.

I created a very basic userscript couple of months ago and a few users installed it.
When I released an update, I changed the namespace from http://example.com to https://example.com not knowing that changing the namespace from http to https will mean a different script.

Now when the users tried to update their first script, they ended up with 2 different version of my script at the same time.. I mean instead of the new version replacing the old version, both versions are now active on my users browser.

How do I solve this problem?
Thanks in advance.